# Is using a hidden <input> with its value set to something in php to then pass to jquery bad?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme and I have a contact form that uses jquery to check for errors and then show a confirmation message if the email was sent successfully.

Before the confirmation email is shown, I want to show a loading.gif so the user knows it is doing something. My problem is assigning the img SRC url in jquery, as I do not want it to be fixed.

I want to set it to get the site url and then add the image name to it.

As you cannot parse PHP in js I thought that maybe I could cheat and do the PHP on the form page using a hidden input that passes the data to JS.

So i'd have a

```
<li class="hiddenurl">
    <input name="hiddenurl" value="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
</li>
```

and then in jquery i'd set the value to a variable and then in JS:

```
$(this).parent().append('<img src="'+variable+'/library/images/loading.gif" etc
```

Is this a bad way of doing it?

Comment: Nope, not really.. its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you cannot parse PHP in js

Wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($some_php_variable); ?>;
</script>
```

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) makes any PHP variable (except Resources) instantly parseable by JavaScript. It's sort of like [`var_export`](http://php.net/var-export) but for use in JavaScript instead of PHP.

Comment: I think what they meant is that you can't put `<?php ... ?>` inside a `.js` file, which is correct. However, your approach is the one I use as well (though not with PHP).

Comment: Yes, I meant that you couldn't use php code inside a .js file. Where can I set that variable though? I don't think putting in the site's head is good practice as it will only ever be called on the contact form page, which is why I was looking for a tighter way of doing it.

Comment: Well, I prefer to put a `<script>` tag at the top of my page that PHP can dump some variables into, then have the external JS file get those variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily a 'bad' way of doing it, but jQuery provides the .data() method to accomplish exactly this. You can use it to add your own "data-" annotations in the HTML and then retrieve/set them in your JS code.

See the jQuery Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

So I would use this to add the url to the image and in the JS grab it out..

If you were looking to just pass the URL as a variable in the JS, then @Kolink has the correct answer for this.

Comment: This looks like an interesting method! But the data that is fed into js seems to be grabbed from within a div/span, so i would have to make a hidden div with the url and that would be similar to the input? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In your specific situation there would need to be an element on the page with the attribute. In other situations it can be very useful though. I'd recommend @Kolink's answer

Answer (score 0):

this cant be bad , as it doesnt harm anything .. but if you only want to get the url then why not ..

```
window.location
```

like so

```
window.location.pathname // outputs "/questions/14526659/is-using-a-hidden-input-with-its-value-set-to-something-in-php-to-then-pass-to"

window.location.origin  // outputs http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: unfortunately I need to use php to get the location of the theme, and it could be called anything, so I need it to be more flexible! thanks though